# Qt : catched mouseMoseEvent dont interact with QWebView html page element

Tags: c++, qt, qwebview, qmouseevent

I catch the `mouseMoveEvent` of my `QWebView` for restarting a timer of a screensaver. The problem is that now the `mouseMoveEvent` isnt distribued to the HTML elements so its impossible for example to move a sliding bar on the page.

I use connect to bind `mouseMoveEvent` to the restart slot :

```
QObject::connect(_view, SIGNAL(mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent*)), _mediaPlayer, SLOT(stop()));
```

WebView class :

```
class WebView : public QWebView
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:

    WebView(QString menu) : _menuDesc(menu) {};
    WebView(){};

    void            setMenuDesc(QString menu) {_menuDesc = menu;};
    QString         getMenuDesc() {return _menuDesc;};
    void            setCurrPage(QString page) {_currPage = page;};
    QString         getCurrPage() {return _currPage;};
    void            setCurrCategory(QString page) {_currPage = page;};
    QString         getCurrCategory() {return _currPage;};

    void            mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *)
    {
        emit mouseMoved();
    };

signals :
    void mouseMoved();

private:

    QString             _menuDesc = 0;
    QString             _currPage;
    QString             _currCategory = 0;
};
```

Is there a solution to still catch the signal and pass it to the HTML page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mouseMoveEvent` is not a signal but an event handler. You can reimplement this event handler and let it emit a signal you can connect to if you need that.

Like this:

```
MyWebView::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent * e) {
   emit mouseMoved(); // this would be signal you could connect to.
}
```

Comment: Okay i did as you said. WebView class: `void            mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *)
    {
        emit mouseMoved();
    };

signals :
    void mouseMoved();
`                                                                                                                 Then i connect to the mouseMoved signal: `QObject::connect(_view, SIGNAL(mouseMoved()), _mediaPlayer, SLOT(stop()));`. Is that correct ? The event is not still passed to the html page.

Comment: Did you also click ?. As long as you do not activate mouse tracking a move event will only be triggered between mouse press and mouse release events. You could try the `mousePressEvent` for now.

Comment: And `_view` is of type `WebView` which you derived from QWebView ? And you added the Q_OBJECT macro to the private section ?

Comment: check with `QDebug` whether your mouseMoveEvent() method gets called.

Comment: I click my bar and (still holding left click) i try to pull it down. I edited the post to put my WebView class declaration. I tried with `mousePressEvent` too but i need now a double click to reach the page elements. The first one does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Seems you misunderstand event handler and signal usages.

**mouseMoveEvent** is a member method of QWidget, is not a signal so you cannot connect to it. You can override it in you subclass and emit your own signal.

And if a QWidget's mouse tracking is switched off, mouse move events only occur if a mouse button is pressed while the mouse is being moved. Maybe you need to call **setMouseTracking** too.

Comment: I tried @Aaron answer and setting mouse tracking to true, but cant make my bar slide atm, it works well when i get rid of the mouseMoveEvent override in my class.

Comment: @Robin, in your subclass's mouseMoveEvent code, call QWebView::mouseMoveEvent(event)  before or after emit the signal, or the base class's handler won't get excuted.

Comment: Okay i see, sounds logical and works :). Thank you all !